# How to resolve merge conflict without merging branch

Tags: git, merge, branching-and-merging

We use a `production` branch and a `test` branch.
When we develop a new `feature` we branch it off `production` and make changes.
When finished we merge it into `test` for it to be tested with all other features that are also in `test`. Sometimes this results in merge conflicts as the `feature` branch has changes on files that has also changed in `test`.

Bitbucket suggests to merge `test` into `feature`, however this is problematic as changes from `test` that should not be released will become part of `feature`. And at the time we want to merge ´feature´ into `production` sometimes changes from `test` are included which should not happen.

How should we resolve the conflicts when merging `feature` into `test` without having `feature` affected so that we can merge `feature` into `production` later on without including additional changes?

Comment: You can't fix this with git. If you have mutiple parallel tracks of work that may be touching the same files, but want to keep them independently merge-able into trunk, you'll have conflicts when you try to integrate them elsewhere.

Comment: If you test several features together why not merge those to production together? When you select only one feature to merge it may bring some bugs to production branch that was fixed by other features.
You might take a look at different branching strategies like [github flow](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/github-flow) or [git flow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow)

Comment: @zerocukor287 The features can only be merged to P when they are finished testing, usually one can not wait for the other (different teams involved). I know git flow, not sure if that would completely solve it, but was wondering if it can be handled better within the current flow.

Comment: Two things that will maybe help: when merging features to production branch, make sure you merge them in the same order as you did for the testing branch T, and then make sure that you have `rerere` enabled.

Comment: That being said, sometimes you just need to fix conflicts again in a workflow like this.

Comment: You have to solve the conflicts twice. Your workflow is a good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I know of is to create a branch based on the `feature` branch, e.g. `feature-to-test` and solve the merge conflicts on that by merging test into that.
In that way you wont pollute `feature` with changes from `test` which you don't want to become part of `production` before they are ready.

Comment: Downside is you spend time testing a changeset that is **not** the one you actually plan to merge if that testing passes.

Comment: @jonrsharpe true, but that is the result of having a test-branch in the first place rather than any technique you use to get things on to said test-branch. As long as new features doesn't interact to much with each other it shouldn't be a problem.